# Python : reverse keys and values in dictionary considering strings and not caracters

Tags: python, dictionary

i have to invert keys and values in a dictionary but it doesn't take into account the whole string, it considers character by character.

My code is as follows :

```
locat= {1: 'aa', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ba', 4: 'ab'}
location = {}
for e, char in locat.items():
        location.setdefault(char, []).append(e)
```

I have as a result :

```
{'aa': [1, 1], 'ab': [2, 4, 2, 4], 'ba': [3]}
```

But I am expecting this result :

```
{'aa': [1], 'ab': [2, 4], 'ba':[3]}
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Comment: please provide the fill code (location2) is not part of the code pasted.

Comment: don't use dict as a variable

Comment: Is `dict` supposed to be `locat`? If so, your code is correct, and works correctly on both Python 2 & Python 3.

Comment: @Amy21: The code you've posted is actually correct. Are you by any chance running that cell multiple times?

Comment: dict is locat indeed

Comment: @NickilMaveli no I am not running it multiple times

Comment: Your code *does* produce the expected result.

Comment: I agree with @NickilMaveli; if I run your code, I get your expected result.

Comment: Why did you change `locat` back to `dict`? As abccd said earlier you should _not_ use `dict` as a variable name. It causes no harm here, but it can lead to mysterious bugs with cryptic error messages. Instead, you should've changed the name of that `dict` in both places to the same thing (like `locat`).

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for your advice, I have change it

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I am using it in a loop so maybe the problem comes from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
c={}
dict = {1: 'aa', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ba', 4: 'ab'}
for e, char in dict.items():
    c.setdefault(char, []).append(e)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'aa': [1], 'ab': [2, 4], 'ba': [3]}
```

Or

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(list)
dict = {1: 'aa', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ba', 4: 'ab'}
for e, char in dict.items():
    c[char] += [e]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aa': [1], 'ab': [2, 4], 'ba': [3]})
```

---

defaultdict to dict:

**python3.x** you can use

```
import builtins
print(builtins.dict(c))
```

**Python 2.x** try this:

```
import __builtin__
print(__builtin__.dict(c))
```

---

By the way,don't use **dict** as a variable.

Comment: Thank you, and how can I access only the dictionary without having the defaultdict ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
location = {1: 'aa', 2: 'ab', 3: 'ba', 4: 'ab'}
location_new={}
for i,s in location.items():
    if s in location_new:
        location_new[s]+=[i]
    else:
        location_new[s]=[i]
print(location_new)
```

output:

```
{'aa': [1], 'ab': [2, 4], 'ba': [3]}
```

Remainder:
Don't use `dict` or `list` or any other types as variables, it *will* cause errors later on.

Answer (score 1):

Using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
{v:[k for k in dict if dict[k] == v] for v in dict.itervalues()}
```

I use list comprehension `[k for k in dict if dict[k]` to calculate the value for every key

Comment: Adding some explanation about the code will help future users to understand the answer.